# Remove every character after a certain character in a string in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm opening texturepacks for my game and am holding filenames in a table, however when I use os.listdir() it returns the filenames with the extensions. Is there a way I could remove all characters after the dot that marks the file extension?

Example: Change `'Body.png'` into `'Body'` or `'Head.jpeg'` into `'Head'`

Thanks!

Comment: Note, the first answer there is great except that they're using python2.x.  For python3.x, you just need to use a `print` function.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).  It's useful for splitting file extensions out of filenames.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.splitext('Body.png')
('Body', '.png')
>>> os.path.splitext('Body.png')[0]
'Body'
```

Comment: How would I use this.

Comment: or more simply >>> path = "c:/temp/x.txt"  then split the path and take the first part...  
>>> path.split(".")[0]
'c:/temp/x'

Comment: @DanPatterson -- But quite possibly wrong... What if you have a filename:  `path = 'c:/temp.foo/x.txt'`?  I suppose that `path.rsplit(".", 1)[0]` is maybe more robust?  But I'd rather rely on a library function that is meant to handle all of these weird corner cases...

Comment: @mgilson You are quite right with the `rsplit`. It's more correct. Nevertheless, apart from the robustness of a library it's also semantically much clearer to use  `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: @TimHoffmann -- Yep, I definitely agree.  Semantics are more important than people give them credit for I think ...

Comment: Good point, I have never used "." in folder names, I just got into the habit of using raw notation and "_" instead of spaces, perhaps for that reason.

Comment: Rsplit worked great for me. Thanks @mgilson.